# How can I know the type of my data in c++?

Tags: python, c++

Is there is a functions that tells you what kind of you data you're dealing with in C++?

In python there exist the `type()` function but is there is one in C++?

```
x = 20
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I used c++, but as I recall, you have to explicitly say the type of the variable when it's declared, for example `int x;`.  So in most (nearly all?) cases, you would have no need to discover the type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct equivalent is `typeid(var).name()`.
However, in C++ and other static typed languages, this is rarely useful; outside of inheritance and generic programming, any variable can only be a single type, and can't change type.

Note that you have to have `#include <typeinfo>` for `typeid` to be defined.